# TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable - python 3 - try to post base64 image data

Tags: json, python-3.x

i received this error after try convert data to json to post request

> TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable

my code

```
dict_data: dict = {
  'img': base64.b64encode(urlopen(obj['recognition_image_path']).read())
}
json_data: str = json.dumps(dict_data)
```

i read image from url, convert it to base64, after i received error when try convert data to json.
Please help

Comment: I am getting this too - but only when running within Docker!

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert to `string` first by calling `.decode`, since you can't JSON-serialize a `bytes` without knowing its encoding.

(`base64.b64encode` returns a `bytes`, not a `string`.)

```py
import base64
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

dict_data: dict = {
  'img': base64.b64encode(urlopen(obj['recognition_image_path']).read()).decode('utf8')
}
json_data: str = json.dumps(dict_data)
```

edit: rewrite answer to address actual question, encode/decode

Answer (score 2):

I will do it in a two step process:

1. First **encode** the image file into BASE64
2. Then **decode** the encoded file

And then transmit back the JSON data using the decoded file.

**Here is an example:**

Let's say the image file is **is_image_file**

1. Encode the image file by:

`enc_image_file = base64.b64encode(is_image_file.read())`

2. Next decode it by:

`send_image_file = enc_image_file.decode()`

Finally transmit the `data` using `send_image_file` as JsonResponse to wherever it would be used.

Of course, add `import base64` before calling the function.

**Note:** Using `json.dumps(dict_data)` one gets a string which will not load the image/s.